# For loop not completing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, for-loop, asynchronous, promise

I wrote a function that will organize addresses based on distance. It working fine until I input 5 address. After that the for loop will only run 2 times instead of the intended 5 times. What am I doing wrong?

```
async function getNextStop() {
    const lis = document.querySelectorAll('.stop');
    const stops = Array.prototype.slice.call(lis);
    const stopItems = Array.prototype.slice.call(lis);
    lis.forEach((i) => {
      i.remove();
    });
    for (let stopsIndex = 0; stopsIndex < stops.length; stopsIndex++) {
      const distances = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < stopItems.length; i++) {
        let lastLi = document.querySelectorAll('li');
        lastLi = lastLi[lastLi.length - 1];
        const newDis = await getDistance(lastLi.querySelector('address').innerText,
          stopItems[i].querySelector('address').innerText)
          .then(response => response);
        distances.push(newDis);
      }
      const lowest = distances.indexOf(Math.min(...distances));
      ul.appendChild(stopItems[lowest]);
      stopItems.splice(lowest, 1);
      console.log(stopsIndex, stops.length, stops, stopItems);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191824/discussion-on-question-by-colton-pemberton-for-loop-not-completing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: I'm not psychic - I found the `getDistance` function on the OP's site, which he linked to in the chat :p
>
> But I am psychic about the rate limiting :p

First ... handle errors in `getDistance` - otherwise the promise will be forever pending - so, forever `await`ed

```
function getDistance(thing1, thing2) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const request = {
            origin: thing1,
            destination: thing2,
            travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        };
        directionsService.route(request, (result, status) => {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                resolve(Number(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '')));
            } else {
                reject({result, status});
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Second - as you've determined you are limited to 10 requests per second, then limit your rate

```
async function getNextStop() {
    const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    const lis = document.querySelectorAll('.stop');
    const stops = Array.prototype.slice.call(lis);
    const stopItems = Array.prototype.slice.call(lis);
    lis.forEach((i) => {
        i.remove();
    });
    for (let stopsIndex = 0; stopsIndex < stops.length; stopsIndex++) {
        const distances = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < stopItems.length; i++) {
            let lastLi = document.querySelectorAll('li');
            lastLi = lastLi[lastLi.length - 1];
            await delay(100); // 10 per second
            const newDis = await getDistance(lastLi.querySelector('address').innerText, stopItems[i].querySelector('address').innerText);
                // remove the next line, it is redundant
                //.then(response => response);
            distances.push(newDis);
        }
        const lowest = distances.indexOf(Math.min(...distances));
        ul.appendChild(stopItems[lowest]);
        stopItems.splice(lowest, 1);
        console.log(stopsIndex, stops.length, stops, stopItems);
    }
}
```

Additionally you may want to handle errors in getNextStop

```
        try {
            const newDis = await getDistance(lastLiAddress, stopItem.querySelector('address').innerText);
            distances.push(newDis);
        } catch(e) {
            console.error('getDistance failed');
            console.error(e);
            throw e;
        }
```

Though, that shouldn't be necessary if the code calling `getNextStop` has a try/catch to handle any errors

Comment: It's still hitting the limit, but I don't think there's much I can do other than increase the delay. Users will just have to have patients lol

Comment: really, if it's 10 per second, then just make the delay 150 - there's no way you could hit the limit then ... unless you coded the delay wrong :p

Comment: I copied and pasted it lol. It's all good though, it's only a personal project for my resume.